# In Julia using StochasticPrograms.jl package how can I get the @sampler object as a n*m matrix not a vector?

Tags: random, julia, julia-jump, stochastic

In the julia programming language I use StochasticPrograms.jl package to model a two stage stochastic problem. I use @sampler object to develop scenarios and random values. The random variable follows a normal distribution. The @sampler output should be a 3*3 matrix to match the random variable dimension ( d[1:J,1:T], J=3, T=3) defined in the problem.

I have used a few different techniques to get the output as a 3*3 matrix (one of them is below) but no luck.

```
using StochasticPrograms
@sampler SimpleSampler = begin
        N::MvNormal 
    
        SimpleSampler(µ, Σ) = new(MvNormal(µ, Σ))
    
    @sample Scenario begin

        x = rand(sampler.N) 
        
        return @scenario d = reshape(x,3,3)
    end
end

μ=[4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4]

Σ=[
    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
]

s = SimpleSampler(μ,Σ)
s()
```

and the output is:

```
d: [3.2222636794881696 1.9732554309220443 3.0941572984285233; 3.421615040079402 3.145688781906985 2.856241404036557; 3.0571013553323985 4.24134467488927 5.800220182172864]
```

Comment: The output looks like a 3by3 matrix? What's wrong exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @OscarDowson mentions in the comment, the output *is* a 3x3 matrix. The semi-colons in the output denote the end of one row and the beginning of the next.

It seems like you are outputting this with something like: `print("d: ", d)`. Instead, try using `display(d)`. As the documentation for `print` says:

> Write ... a canonical (un-decorated) text representation
> The
> representation used by print includes minimal formatting

the output of a `print` call is pretty barebones. I haven't looked into the reasons, but my interpretation is that its priority is to be consistent and machine-readable. For human readability, `display` is better.

**Edit**: Oh, and please read through the [Performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/) in the manual in case you haven't yet. Having everything as global variables like here will incur performance penalties once you start building this into anything more computationally intensive.